# I can't upload to Google : issue with android exported="true" with OneSignal in manifest.xml

Tags: android, cordova, onesignal

Issue: I have this message when I try to upload my Android app :

You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service, or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without the 'android: exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported

My AndroidManifest.xml file

`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10004" android:versionName="1.0.4" package="com.va.barce" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:exported="true" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.cordova.plugin.camera.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="org.apache.cordova.camera.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/camera_provider_paths" />
        </provider>
        <amazon:enable-feature android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging" android:required="false" xmlns:amazon="http://schemas.amazon.com/apk/res/android" />
        <service android:exported="false" android:name="com.onesignal.ADMMessageHandler" />
        <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.ADMMessageHandler$Receiver" android:permission="com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <action android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.va.barce" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="com.va.barce.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.va.barce.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE" />
</manifest>
```

`

The issue come from Onesignal.
If I upload without the onesignal plugin everything is ok.

Anyhelp will be grateful

Comment: Can't you just update the OneSignal to some newer version?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.onesignal.ADMMessageHandler$Receiver" android:permission="com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.SEND"
        tools:ignore="Instantiatable">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <action android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="handyman.customer.app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: put android:exported="false"